# How to annotate a function in Clojure using core.typed?

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.typed

I have the following simple code:

```clj
; No, test.core isn't the real namespace
(ns test.core
    (:gen-class)
    (:require [clojure.core.typed :refer [ann]]))

(defn -main
  ([]
    (println "Hello, World!"))
  ([x]
    (println "You gave me " x)))
```

How would I annotate the `-main` function using [`core.typed`](https://github.com/clojure/core.typed/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `-main` function has more than one implementation, you need to explicitly use the function type, `Fn`, instead of the short syntax. It would look something like this:

```
(ann -main
     (Fn [-> nil]
         [Any -> nil]))
```

Take a look at the [Functions](https://github.com/clojure/core.typed/wiki/Types#functions) entry, in the core.typed wiki, for more details on the syntax of the function type. Also, take a look at [`cf`](http://clojure.github.io/core.typed/#clojure.core.typed/cf), because it can show you how to type forms.

```
(clojure.core.typed/cf
  (fn ([] (println "Hello, World!"))
      ([x] (println "You gave me " x))))

;; => [(Fn [Any -> nil] [-> nil]) {:then tt, :else ff}]
```